# Please help me to understand how to read statistical tables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Sorry I never learnt from a professor or class how and now when I look at them I don't know what to do.

Here is an example.

The Chi Squared table,

http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~mga/401/tables/Chi-square-table.pdf

What is meant by saying the shaded area is equal to $\alpha$ for $\chi^{2}=\chi_{\alpha}^{2}$ ?

Does the number in the chart refer to the x value at which $\alpha$ of all the mass has already occurred? for example

$df=5$,  $\chi_{0.950}^{2}$ in the chart is $1.145$.

Does that mean that at $x=1.145$ with $df=5$ , everything up to and before $x=1.145$ is $95$% of the total mass.

Sorry that it is very trivial, I think I just need someone to explain.

Similarly, for student t, is it the same?

http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/gerstman/StatPrimer/t-table.pdf

I am not sure I understand what is meant by one tail or two tails ( I think maybe because it is symmetric)? and Fisher? are all these tables following the same basic organization? The links provided are what I am referencing. I am looking for someone to please just help me understand.

Anyways, thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first table, consider the graph. The graph indicates $\alpha$ is the area to the *right* of $\chi^2_{\alpha}$. For a distribution with 5 degrees of freedom, $X^2_{0.950}$ is the value at which 95% of the mass falls to the *right* of (and 5% of the mass falls to the left of).

As an alternative, consider the graph included with [this](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~athienit/Tables/Ztable.pdf) z-table. The graph indicates $\alpha$ is the area to the *left* of $z_{\alpha}$. The convention varies from table to table.

When a graph is not included with the table, one hopes other information provided clarifies the convention in use. In the case of your t-table, the phrase "cum. prob" suggests the table tabulates cumulative probabilities, i.e., probabilities of the form $\Pr(X \leq t_{\alpha})$; therefore, in that table, $\alpha$ is the area to the *left* of $t_{\alpha}$.

Comment: so in my example , x=1.145 would actually be the point at which after is 95% of the mass?

Comment: @PersonaA, you are correct. In order for 95% of the mass to lie to the right of $x = 1.145$, we would expect $x$ to lie in the far left of the distribution. A graph of the probability density function of the chi-squared distribution with 5 degrees of freedom, with the x-axis appropriately labeled, confirms our expectations.